# Input from two microphones to bluetooth

Tags: bluetooth, audio

I am a complete noob at arduino, so I apologize if this is a stupid question.

I would like to take input from two microphones and send the output to a bluetooth headset using an Arduino processor? Is this something that can be done with these processors or do I need something more powerful, like a Raspberry Pi?

I don't really need to process the signal at all, simply add the 2 inputs together and divide by 2 to keep the output from clipping.

Comment: There are bluetooth audio modules, which have an audio input or output. You have to search for one of these. Keep in mind that you cannot use a bluetooth serial module like HC-05 or HC-06. The audio mixing can be done via electronic components. This should be easier, that first sampling both audio signals to an Arduino and then output the resulting analog voltage again.

Comment: Your comment on combining the two inputs before digitizing makes perfect sense. Thanks.

Comment: The point was, that the bluetooth audio module should do the digitizing. In this case the Arduino is only used to provide an interface for establishing Bluetooth connections.